# How to assign global variable from subscribe() function and update the view

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am doing the task and I have a problem I can't assign value to global to be seen in the view in angular8. I know what is asynchronous but how to assign the value and update the view.

post-details.component.ts

```
export class PostDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      indexOfPost;
      titles=[];
      subscription: Subscription;
      renderPost:boolean=false;
      constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private getSharedTitles:ShareInfoTitleService,private detectChanges: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.subscription = this.getSharedTitles.getMessage().subscribe((title)=>{
          this.titles=title.titles;
          this.renderPost=true;
          this.detectChanges.markForCheck();

        });
      }    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.indexOfPost=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

      }
    }
```

post-details.component.html

```
<p *ngIf="renderPost">works</p>
```

It does not work. My aim is to show the titles in post-details.component.html. I'll be grateful for the tips.Regards

Comment: Are you sure it is entering the subscribe block? Try logging something to the console in the subscribe block and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, your code looks ok. You need to add more info on how to improve the code. Looks like that the code you pass to subscribe never gets called and we need to know why.

Comment: Looks like you have declared the subscription in the costructor. Maybe call it in `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: nash11. console.log(this.titles) nested in subscribe does work properly

Comment: there is some reason that doesn't work. Do you have any idea

Comment: It should work, Your execution should come in subscribe block and console something. If it is not coming then add catch block and console it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to write too much for a simple task. Just explore **async** pipe and it will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe.

```
export class PostDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

      message$ = this.getSharedTitles.getMessage();

      constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private getSharedTitles:ShareInfoTitleService) {

      }    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.indexOfPost=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

      }
    }
```

In template

```
    <p *ngIf="( message$ | async) as message">{{message.title}}</p>
```

Comment: There is some reason that it doesn't work properly do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async pipe** which unsubscribes auto-magically.

```
export class PostDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      indexOfPost;
      titles: Observable<any> = this.getSharedTitles.getMessage();

      constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,private getSharedTitles:ShareInfoTitleService,private detectChanges: ChangeDetectorRef) {

      }  

      ngOnInit() {
        this.indexOfPost=this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");

      }
    }
```

in template

```
<p *ngIf="(titles | async)">works</p>
```